# goutteでcss属性セレクタが使えない場合の対処

Tags: php, laravel-5, web-scraping

こんにちは。

laravel5+goutteを使ってゴリゴリ情報収集するツール的なものを書いているのですが、
一部サイトでは、ページネーションの設定にaタグにclassを使わずにmode="next"などの特殊な属性で指定している物があり、次ページへのURLを取れずに苦戦しています。

取得先のHTML

```
<div id="pagenation">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a mode="prev" href="hogehoge/1">もどる</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a mode="current" href="hogehoge/2">-</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a mode="next" href="hogehoge/3">すすむ</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

取得用コード

```
$url = $crawler->filter('div.pagenation')->filter("a[rel='next']")->attr('href');
```

aタグにnameなどがあればselectLink()を使う代用案も考えていたのですが、
現時点では、filter部分でのcssセレクタをうまく使う方法が無いか悩んでいます。

お知恵を貸していただけませんでしょうか

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
CSS属性セレクタは使わずまわりくどいですが、foreachを使って
条件判定をしつつ、Aタグの中身を評価して一致したらnextと同義であるという考えにしました。

```
 $crawler->filter('ul')->each(function ($row) use (&$URI) {
      $row->filter('li')->each(function ($pagenate) use (&$URI) {
           if ($pagenate->text() == 'すすむ') {
                $URL = $pagenate->filter('a')->attr('href');
           }
      });
 });
```